# Does extractPrediction() support factors?

Tags: r, r-factor, r-caret

I am trying to use a random forest model as one of several models that I am testing including neural networks (`nnet` and `neuralnet`) all using the convenient `caret` package. The random forest model supports the use of factors, so for this model, rather than convert the factors to numeric contrasts using `dummyVars()`, I thought I'd just keep them as factors. This works fine in the training step (`train()` ):

```
library(caret)

#Set dependent
seed = 123
y = "Sepal.Length"

#Partition (iris) data into train and test sets
set.seed(seed)
train.idx = createDataPartition(y = iris[,y], p = .8, list = FALSE)
train.set = iris[train.idx,]
test.set = iris[-train.idx,]

train.set = data.frame(train.set)
test.set = data.frame(test.set)

#Select features
features = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species")
mod.features = paste(features, collapse = " + ")

#Create formula
mod.formula = as.formula(paste(y, mod.features, sep = " ~ "))

#Train model
mod <- train(mod.formula, data = train.set,
             method = "rf")
```

but when I try to use `extractPrediction()`, it fails:

```
#Test model with extractPrediction()
testPred = extractPrediction(models = list(mod),
                             testX = test.set[,features],
                             testY = test.set[,y])
```

> Error in predict.randomForest(modelFit, newdata) :  variables in the
>   training data missing in newdata

Now, as far as I can see, this is because during the call to train(), 1-hot encoding / contrasts are created for the factors, and as such some new variable names are created. It seems that the base predict() method works fine even with factors:

```
#Test model with predict()
testPred = predict(mod$finalModel, 
                   newData = test.set[, features])
```

And when I convert my factors to numeric contrasts using `dummyVars()`, `extractPrediction()` works fine:

```
#Train and test model using dummyVar
data.dummies = dummyVars(~.,data = iris)
data = predict(data.dummies, newdata = iris)

set.seed(seed)
train.idx = createDataPartition(y = data[,y], p = .8, list = FALSE)
train.set = data[train.idx,]
test.set = data[-train.idx,]

features = c("Sepal.Width", "Petal.Length", "Petal.Width", "Species.setosa",
             "Species.versicolor", "Species.virginica")
mod.features = paste(features, collapse = " + ")

#Create formula
mod.formula = as.formula(paste(y, mod.features, sep = " ~ "))

train.set = data.frame(train.set)
test.set = data.frame(test.set)

mod <- train(mod.formula, data = train.set,
             method = "rf")

testPred = extractPrediction(models = list(mod),
                             testX = test.set[,features],
                             testY = test.set[,y])
```

Can anyone explain to me why this is? It would be great to get `extractPrediction()` working with factors for use in my multi-model testing pipeline. I suppose I could just convert everything using `dummyVars()` at the begining, but I'm intrigued to know why `extractPrediction()` isn't working with factors in this case, even when `predict()` does work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use the default function interface instead of the one which uses a formula, you should be in business.

```
set.seed(1234)
mod_formula <- train(
    Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length + Petal.Width + Species
  , data = iris
  , method = "rf")

test_formula <- extractPrediction(
    models = list(mod_formula)
)

set.seed(1234)
mod_default <- train(
    y = iris$Sepal.Length
  , x = iris[, c('Sepal.Width', 'Petal.Length', 'Petal.Width', 'Species')]
  , method = "rf")

test_default <- extractPrediction(
  models = list(mod_default)
)
```